# Xcode Linked Framework Not Found in Swift Project with Target Dependencies

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, swift4

I have a Swift Project with a linked framework, built as project target dependencies.

So I have specified the **Target Dependencies** and the dependency target framework in the **Link Binary With Libraries**.

I have set up the **Bridging Header** for that framework as header file and the **Objective-C Bridging Header**.

Everything works when using that build product in the `Frameworks` folder's group directly. Of course in that case I cannot debug the inner framework sources.

So when I use the Target Dependency as sub-project, Xcode9 complains that the public header of that framework - specified in the `Bridging-Header`

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFrameworkImports.h>
```

has not been found.

I guess if I must manually specify the Product Build folder as `MACRO` in the `Frameworks Search Path` - considering that the build products belong to a sub-project, so I cannot get that path from the macro `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`.